# Select only most recent record for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will allow me to grab ONLY the most recent records for each month, and then sum them.  Below is an example of my table.  What I want to be able to do is select the Prior month.  If I can do that, I can figure out how to grab 2 months ago, a year ago, the quarter etc.

Looking below, if we are in October, I want to grab and sum up only the records on 9/24/2014 8:57

I'm also going to want to write a separate query that does the same thing, but for August.

My goal is to do this by Declaring and Setting variables. Currently I'm using this in each of my where clauses.  I'm just stuck with figuring out the max(date) part of what I need to do.

```
DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonth = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()),    
GETDATE())))
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonth datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevMonth = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))


DECLARE @FirstDayofPrevMonthPrior datetime
SET @FirstDayofPrevMonthPrior = dateadd(MONTH, -2,@FirstDayofPrevMonth)
DECLARE @LastDayofPrevMonthPrior datetime
SET @LastDayofPrevMonthPrior = DATEADD(MONTH,-2,@LastDayofPrevMonth)
```

[image]

**UPDATE:  Here's what I have used as my final working solution:**

```
SELECT SUM(NumofAccounts) AS Total
                FROM dbo.Summary
                WHERE ImportDate =  (select MAX(importdate) from AllAcctInfoSummary 
                    where year(importdate) = year(@LastDayofPrevMonth)
                    and month(importdate) = month(@LastDayofPrevMonth))
                    group by ImportDate
```

Comment: You may want to include the test data in text form for easy cut'n'paste.

Comment: are you specifically wanting to use variables? because there are easier ways to do it

Comment: I don't have to use variables no, not at all.  I just have them all written in my existing Stored Procedure and figured I'd plug them in.  This is all for a temp table i'm using for a report.  I'm open to whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select sum(some_column)
from my_table
where importdate = 
(select max(importdate) 
from my_table
where year(importdate) = 2014 
and month(importdate) = 10)
group by importdate
```

You can replace the 2014 and 10 with variables after setting the year and month you want.  The query above is logically what you want, you can just tinker with the variables you use.  You could also use your FirstDayofPrevMonth variable and call YEAR and MONTH on it to get the correct values to compare to your table.

Comment: ok, so I'll be da##ed.  Once again I danced around the solution.  This works. I just have to find a way to plug in my variables.  It'd be really helpful though if I could grab the last day there is data in the table for the month I'm searching for

Comment: @donviti If you want the day just use DAY(ImportDate) to get the day from a date.  If I misunderstand what you want, just give me an example.

Comment: on month(importdate) = 10  I want to put in my variable 'month(importdate) = @FirstDayofPrevMonth'

Comment: Can't I use my variables instead of where you have year = 2014 and month = 10?   That's ultimately where I need to be.  I'm monkeying around over here, but not getting it

Comment: @donviti What error are you getting?  FirstDayofPrevMonth is a datetime so I think it would need to be: month(importdate) = month(@FirstDayofPrevMonth)

Answer (score 2):

this will get you a sum for every greatest available day of every month

```
select ImportDate, sum(NumOfAccounts)
from mytable t1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t2 where t2.ImportDate > t1.ImportDate
    and month(t2.ImportDate) = month(t1.ImportDate)
    and year(t2.ImportDate) = year(t1.ImportDate)
) 
group by ImportDate
order by ImportDate
```

if you only want the previous month add the following to your where

```
and month(dateadd(month,-1,getdate())) = month(ImportDate)
and year(dateadd(month,-1,getdate())) = year(ImportDate)
```

Same query using analytic functions, which should be a little faster

```
select ImportDate, sum(NumOfAccounts)
from (
    select *,
    rank() over (partition by month(ImportDate), year(ImportDate) order by ImportDate desc) rk
    from mytable
) t1 where rk = 1
group by ImportDate
order by ImportDate
```

Comment: I like this solution a little better.  You guys are amazing out here.  Thanks.  Ultimately, like I said, I'm going to want Previous month.  Current Quarter, Prior year same month, so this allows me (i believe) to insert my variables